# NotImplementedError: Cannot convert a symbolic Tensor (up_sampling2d_4_target:0) to a numpy array

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, tensorflow2.0, tensor

> NotImplementedError: Cannot convert a symbolic Tensor
>   (up_sampling2d_4_target:0) to a numpy array.

got following error

```
import keras.backend as K
from keras.optimizers import Adam
from keras.losses import binary_crossentropy

## intersection over union
def IoU(y_true, y_pred, eps=1e-6):
    if np.max(y_true) == 0.0:
        return IoU(1-y_true, 1-y_pred) ## empty image; calc IoU of zeros
    intersection = K.sum(y_true * y_pred, axis=[1,2,3])
    union = K.sum(y_true, axis=[1,2,3]) + K.sum(y_pred, axis=[1,2,3]) - intersection
    return -K.mean( (intersection + eps) / (union + eps), axis=0)
```

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- NotImplementedError                       Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in 
>        14 
>        15 while True:
>   ---> 16     loss_history = fit()
>        17     if np.min([mh.history['val_loss'] for mh in loss_history]) < -0.2:
>        18         break
>
> in fit()
>         1 def fit():
>   ----> 2     seg_model.compile(optimizer=Adam(1e-3, decay=1e-6), loss=IoU, metrics=['binary_accuracy'])
>         3 
>         4     step_count = min(MAX_TRAIN_STEPS, train_df.shape[0]//BATCH_SIZE)
>         5     aug_gen = create_aug_gen(make_image_gen(train_df))
>
> ~/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/training/tracking/base.py
>   in _method_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs)
>       455     self._self_setattr_tracking = False  # pylint: disable=protected-access
>       456     try:
>   --> 457       result = method(self, *args, **kwargs)
>       458     finally:
>       459       self._self_setattr_tracking = previous_value  # pylint: disable=protected-access
>
> ~/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training.py
>   in compile(self, optimizer, loss, metrics, loss_weights,
>   sample_weight_mode, weighted_metrics, target_tensors, distribute,
>   **kwargs)
>       371 
>       372       # Creates the model loss and weighted metrics sub-graphs.
>   --> 373       self._compile_weights_loss_and_weighted_metrics()
>       374 
>       375       # Functions for train, test and predict will
>
> ~/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/training/tracking/base.py
>   in _method_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs)
>       455     self._self_setattr_tracking = False  # pylint: disable=protected-access
>       456     try:
>   --> 457       result = method(self, *args, **kwargs)
>       458     finally:
>       459       self._self_setattr_tracking = previous_value  # pylint: disable=protected-access
>
> ~/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training.py
>   in _compile_weights_loss_and_weighted_metrics(self, sample_weights)
>   1651       #                   loss_weight_2 * output_2_loss_fn(...) +
>   1652       #                   layer losses.
>   -> 1653       self.total_loss = self._prepare_total_loss(masks)    1654     1655   def _prepare_skip_target_masks(self):
>
> ~/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training.py
>   in _prepare_total_loss(self, masks)    1711     1712           if
>   hasattr(loss_fn, 'reduction'):
>   -> 1713             per_sample_losses = loss_fn.call(y_true, y_pred)    1714             weighted_losses = losses_utils.compute_weighted_loss(
>   1715                 per_sample_losses,
>
> ~/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/losses.py
>   in call(self, y_true, y_pred)
>       219       y_pred, y_true = tf_losses_util.squeeze_or_expand_dimensions(
>       220           y_pred, y_true)
>   --> 221     return self.fn(y_true, y_pred, **self._fn_kwargs)
>       222 
>       223   def get_config(self):
>
> in IoU(y_true, y_pred, eps)
>         5 ## intersection over union
>         6 def IoU(y_true, y_pred, eps=1e-6):
>   ----> 7     if np.max(y_true) == 0.0:
>         8         return IoU(1-y_true, 1-y_pred) ## empty image; calc IoU of zeros
>         9     intersection = K.sum(y_true * y_pred, axis=[1,2,3])
>
> <**array_function** internals> in amax(*args, **kwargs)
>
> ~/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py in
>   amax(a, axis, out, keepdims, initial, where)    2619     """    2620
>   return _wrapreduction(a, np.maximum, 'max', axis, None, out,
>   -> 2621                           keepdims=keepdims, initial=initial, where=where)    2622     2623
>
> ~/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py in
>   _wrapreduction(obj, ufunc, method, axis, dtype, out, **kwargs)
>        88                 return reduction(axis=axis, out=out, **passkwargs)
>        89 
>   ---> 90     return ufunc.reduce(obj, axis, dtype, out, **passkwargs)
>        91 
>        92
>
> ~/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py
>   in **array**(self)
>       734   def **array**(self):
>       735     raise NotImplementedError("Cannot convert a symbolic Tensor ({}) to a numpy"
>   --> 736                               " array.".format(self.name))
>       737 
>       738   def **len**(self):
>
> NotImplementedError: Cannot convert a symbolic Tensor
>   (up_sampling2d_4_target:0) to a numpy

array.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `numpy` with a tensorflow `Tensor` they're two different things.

The problem is here:

```
if np.max(y_true) == 0.0:
    return IoU(1-y_true, 1-y_pred) ## empty image; calc IoU of zeros
```

You need these lines instead:

```
is_zero = K.equal(y_true, 0)
y_true = K.switch(is_zero, 1-y_true, y_true)
y_pred = K.switch(is_zero, 1-y_pred, y_pred)
```

Comment: can you make it as if statement like above? not sure how to convert it

Comment: It's in the answer, that's the replacement.